# is it possible to delay the execution of a timer triggered azure function?

Tags: azure-functions

I have a timer that runs periodically. Sometimes another function (triggered by a different event) does the work of the timer as cleanup of it's job. Is it possible to tell azure 'pretend this timer just triggered, and delay until it's next scheduled time'.

There are 2 modes 'at this cron selected time (eg: at 10 minutes past every hour)', and on a schedule '10 minutes after you last executed'.

My timers are currently in the latter mode.
I'm using functions v2.

Answer (score 2):

Timer trigger function schedules are fixed and cannot be updated without updating your application, so what you're describing isn't really possible.

If you need some dynamic control over the scheduling of work, another option you have is to use [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview). Specifically, there is a [Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview#pattern-4-monitoring) pattern which demonstrates how you can create long-running processes which execute on a dynamic schedule. Using this pattern, you could check for the last cleanup time whenever your [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-timers) expires, and then either execute the logic or schedule the next check e.g. 10 minutes later.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you have two functions doing (partialy) the same thing? I would consider having the Function that does the work of the timer as cleanup to have it *not* do the work of the timed Function. It could trigger the other Function to do the work for him. You could consider using, for instance, an HttpTrigger or a QueueTrigger.

As far as your question goes: Functions should be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). I would consider refactoring the cleanup Function to be smart and check to see if there's work to be done. It there is none, just end the execution. Otherwise have it clean up whatever it needs to.

Comment: The functions in question are able to be executed multiple times, the 'cleanup' relates to what work to do next to avoid duplicate work. Most of the time (probably every time, except when exceptions occur) the function that just executed knows what to do next, so can just go and do it, without having to wait for the timer function to trigger. This leads to better system behaviour. If i was to use the timer to do so, then there would be duplicate (non-destructive, but cpu intensive) behaviour.